Redux-persist and Asynchstorage not persisting data when I restart my Expo app
Sign Up component

import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithCredential,
} from "firebase/auth";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { GoogleSignin } from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";
import { SvgXml } from "react-native-svg";
import tw from "twrnc";
import logo from "../../assets/logo.png";
import { auth } from "../../firebase/firebaseConfig";
import { signUpFailure, signUpSuccess } from "../../store/actions/authActions";

const SignUp = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [fullName, setFullname] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const [confirmPasswordVisible, setConfirmPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigation = useNavigation();



  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId:
        "818686588230-5n1ucm1ompk36d2ivtf45e4d5fb8qntr.apps.googleusercontent.com", // Replace with your web client ID from Firebase
      offlineAccess: true,
    });
  }, []);

  const signup = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const user = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      setUserInfo(user);

      console.log("User info:", user); // Log the user's information

      const idToken = user.idToken;
      const googleCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
      const userCredential = await signInWithCredential(auth, googleCredential);
      const userID = userCredential.user.uid;

      const userData = {
        email: userCredential.user.email,
        id: userID,
        name: user.user.name,
        photo: user.user.photo,
      };

      await AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(userData));

      dispatch(signUpSuccess(userData));
      navigation.navigate("Home");
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e.message);
      dispatch(signUpFailure(e.message));
      console.error("Google sign-in error:", e); // Log the error
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleSignUp = async () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      setError("Passwords do not match");
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      const userID = userCredential.user.uid;

      const userData = {
        email,
        id: userID,
        fullName,
        photo: userInfo ? userInfo.user.photo : null,
      };

      await AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(userData));

      dispatch(signUpSuccess(userData));
      navigation.navigate("Home");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error storing data:", error.message);
      // Handle AsyncStorage error (e.g., show error to user)
      setError("Failed to store user data. Please try again.");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };


store/actions/authActions.js
export const SIGNUP_SUCCESS = "SIGNUP_SUCCESS";
export const SIGNUP_FAILURE = "SIGNUP_FAILURE";

export const signUpSuccess = (userData) => ({
  type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
  payload: { userData },
});

export const signUpFailure = (error) => ({
  type: SIGNUP_FAILURE,
  payload: { error },
});

export const LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";

export const logout = () => ({
  type: LOGOUT,
});


store/reducers/authReducer.js**
import { SIGNUP_SUCCESS, SIGNUP_FAILURE, LOGOUT } from "../actions/authActions";

const initialState = {
isAuthenticated: false,
user: null,
userID: null,
fullName: null,
photo: null,
error: null,
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) =\> {
switch (action.type) {
case SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
const { email, userID, fullName, photo } = action.payload.userData;
return {
...state,
isAuthenticated: true,
user: email,
userID,
fullName,
photo,
error: null,
};
case SIGNUP_FAILURE:
return {
...state,
isAuthenticated: false,
user: null,
userID: null,
fullName: null,
photo: null,
error: action.payload.error,
};
case LOGOUT:
return {
...state,
isAuthenticated: false,
user: null,
userID: null,
fullName: null,
photo: null,
error: null,
};
default:
return state;
}
};

export default authReducer;


Store


import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import shopReducer from "./reducers/shopReducer";
import serviceReducer from "./reducers/serviceReducer";
import musikaReducer from "./reducers/musikaReducer";
import foodReducer from "./reducers/foodReducer";
import authReducer from "./reducers/authReducer";
import shortStayReducer from "./reducers/ShortStayReducer";

const persistConfig = {
key: "root",
storage: AsyncStorage,
whitelist: \["auth"\],
};

const rootReducer = {
shop: shopReducer,
service: serviceReducer,
musika: musikaReducer,
food: foodReducer,
auth: persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer),
shortStay: shortStayReducer,
};

const store = configureStore({
reducer: rootReducer,
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =\>
getDefaultMiddleware({
serializableCheck: false,
}),
});

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };


trying to persist authentication using asynchStorage and Redux-persist but every time I restart the app it keeps Loading "Loading user data..."on the Account below:

import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "../store/actions/authActions";
import tw from "twrnc";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const Account = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isAuthenticated, user, fullName, photo } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.auth
  );

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("userID");
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={tw`p-5`}>
      {isAuthenticated ? (
        <View>
          {user ? (
            <View>
              <Text>Logged in as: {user}</Text>
              {fullName && <Text>Full Name: {fullName}</Text>}
              {photo && (
                <Image
                  source={{ uri: photo }}
                  style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50 }}
                />
              )}
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogout}>
                <Text>Logout</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          ) : (
            <Text>Loading user data...</Text>
          )}
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text>Not logged in</Text>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Account;




Issue Description:
Upon app restart, the Account component displays "Loading user data..." indefinitely, indicating a problem with retrieving stored user data from AsyncStorage via Redux Persist.
Expected Outcome:
The app should persist user authentication data across sessions using AsyncStorage and Redux Persist, displaying user information correctly on app restart.
Steps Taken:
Implemented Redux Persist configuration with AsyncStorage.
Verified AsyncStorage storage and retrieval methods.
Checked action dispatching and reducer logic for sign-up success.
Additional Information:
React Native version: "0.74.1",
Redux and Redux Persist versions: "^6.0.0"
Firebase Authentication method: Google auth
Request:
I need assistance in debugging why the app is unable to retrieve stored user data properly from AsyncStorage via Redux Persist on app restart. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Have you solved it yet?
